# Django 4 Отправка email на адрес юзера посредством SMTP

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

изучаю Django 4, допиливаю свой первый проект, осталось разобраться с отправкой email-сообщений с активацией аккаунта на адреса пользователей через SMTP.
Когда я использую localhost и порт 25(отправка письма вникуда) -- в принципе все работает как надо, когда я пытаюсь подключиться к smtp.yandex.ru -- ничего не происходит, ни отправки сообщения, ни каких-то ошибок, вероятно я где-то ошибся в настройках.

Немножко кода:

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "MAIL@yandex.ru"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

views.py

```
class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    """Контроллер, использующий форму для регистрации"""
    model = SimpleUser
    template_name = 'main/register_user.html'
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:register_done')
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Форма для регистрации нового юзера"""

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Адрес электронной почты')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль(повторно)',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text='Введите пароль еще раз')

    def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        if password1:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        return password1

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2': ValidationError('Введенные пароли не совпадают',
                                                   code='password_mismatch')}
            raise ValidationError(errors)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.is_active = False
        user.is_activated = False
        if commit:
            user.save()
        user_registered.send(RegisterUserForm, instance=user)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = SimpleUser
        fields = {'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',
                  'first_name', 'last_name'}
```

**Сама функция отправки письма с активацией реализована отдельно:**

utilities.py

```
signer = Signer()


def send_activation_notification(user):
    """Функция отправляет подтверждение регистрации на емейл юзера"""

    if ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        host = 'http://' + ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]
    else:
        host = 'http://localhost:8000'
    context = {'user': user,
               'host': host,
               'sign': signer.sign(user.username)}
    subject = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_subject.txt', context)
    body_text = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_body.txt', context)
    user.email_user(subject, body_text)
```

apps.py

```
user_registered = Signal()


def user_registered_dispatcher(sender, **kwargs):
    send_activation_notification(kwargs['instance'])


user_registered.connect(user_registered_dispatcher)
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

В общем, разбиравшись в этом вопросе двое суток, очень многое узнал об устройстве SMTP серверов.

Первое, что необходимо сделать - УБЕДИТЬСЯ в том, что в вашем почтовом аккаунте разрешена отправка писем через smtp сервера(как это сделать вам подскажет гугл)

Второе - не включайте в терминале отладочный smtp сервер django

Третье - правильно выберите EMAIL_PORT

ну и код settings.py прилагаю

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "acc@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "pass"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```